# Prevention of User Tampering the API by Serverless clients which are in sync with the real world client

Tags: audit, research, architecture

As we all know, never trust the client, when they send data to your server. However what if you prevent data manipulation by completely restructuring the architecture to something like the following:
[image: Data]
Here as soon as the User tries to connect, a new instance will generated for that user, and then this virtual client can communicate with the server, all the Human Client will get is a plain HTML showing what the virtual client can see at that instant. He can then instruct the Virtual client to perform a particular action on behalf of him(like lets say click on a particular button).
(Note: Regarding the feasibility of spawning such virtual clients, the app is a simple app, not taking more than 10MB of RAM, and the virtual clients are highly optimized to use less resources, like if there is a Image or a Video not to download it and instead just have its location in text)
(Note 2: The server/backend is completely isolated and can only be accessed by the virtual clients through a secure route/ they are in same local network)
In this scenario can we:

1. Trust the Virtual Client? as it is on our trusted network and as user cannot perform Man in the Middle attacks, use a proxy, tamper the code with something like Dev Tools, etc.
2. Are there any technologies implementing the same or similar behavior's?
3. Is there any other flaws in this system(except the high amount of Computational resources that might be needed to spawn the Virtual Clients)
   (Also note the presence of a load balancer and firewall's to prevent DDOS attacks)

Comment: welcome - to clarify, are you proposing that the user only sees some "cut down" gui via remote desktop/ proxy through eg. their web browser, meanwhile the inner workings of the client ui and its interaction with the backend (eg. html/ js/ etc.) isn't available to the end user on their host?

Comment: @brynk that summarizes it perfectly.

Comment: some related products for you to consider - remote app/ desktop, eg. [xpra](https://xpra.org/) [xfreerdp](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP) [novnc](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC),  commercial eg. [thycotic/ delinea](https://delinea.com/products/secret-server),  saas eg. [aws-appstream-2](https://aws.amazon.com/appstream2/) .. you'd need to build a ui or configure a cut-down browser that reliably prevents users from eg. dev-tools (as far as i'm aware the modern browsers can limit this setting) ... but, at the end of the day, you still **must** sanitise user input!

Comment: also, there's a suite of [cisco products that tackle this problem](https://blogs.cisco.com/security/rdp-and-the-remote-desktop) not to forget about [citrix workspace](https://www.citrix.com/products/citrix-daas/) - and possibly another way of thinking about the problem, whereby software proxies access to the server port (rather than the gui) called [teleport](https://goteleport.com/how-it-works/) (the user must load the gui, but the socket can't be created at will)

Comment: You've really just moved the problem around a bit.  The "virtual client" is just another part of your server-side backend now.  It still has to validate all input coming from the _real_ client.

Comment: @MilesBudnek if you talking about XOR attacks, etc I know it doesn't solve such attacks and that does require sanitizing all inputs. However the virtual client doesn't have to do that but instead the server itself. The main reason why I had this question was, I have a web app(JS) built on Firebase backend, but now anyone can just go into dev tools and change the values being sent to the backend and I wanted to figure out any minimal cost ways of preventing such attacks. Obfuscation and minification just delay's the time taken for such attacks but doesn't stop it completely.

Comment: @mrtechtroid Right, my point is that now they can just go into the dev tools and change what they send to the virtual client.  At some point you have to define your trust boundary and validate any input that comes from outside of it.  All this solution does is move that boundary.

Comment: You've rediscovered ["multi-tier architecture"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)  The usual description is "The user can't directly manipulate the database; he can only communicate with the application server, which is the only component allowed to connect to the database".  You've changed the label from "application server" to "virtual client" but in all respects except the name, it is exactly the 3-Tier Architecture.